# Do I need a visa for entering Gambia?

Tags: visas, refugees, danish-residents

I'm travelling to Gambia for 16 days in December-January.

Do I need a visa?

I have a Travel Document from Denmark (it's a blue passport) and I'm not a citizen of Denmark yet. I'm a citizen of Afghanistan, but I've lived in Denmark for 22 years (if that matters).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Gambia#/media/File:Visa_policy_of_the_Gambia.png

Comment: Hi Paul, I don't know how to interpret the picture you've attached?

Comment: My understanding is that you will need a visa because you are not a **citizen** of Denmark (who have visa free entry to The Gambia).

Answer (score 1):

It appears you will need a visa because you are not a citizen of Denmark (who have visa free entry to The Gambia) but of Afghanistan

[Visa policy of the Gambia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Gambia#)

> Visa exemption
>
> Nationals of the following 104 countries and territories can visit the
>   Gambia without a visa for up to 90 days (unless otherwise noted)

**Afghanistan is not on the visa free list, **neither is an exemption mentioned for permanent residents of visa free countries mentioned**.

On their [UK Embassy](http://www.gambiaembassy.org.uk/embassy-of-the-republic-of-the-gambia/services/documents/) website it says:

> **Citizens** of the United Kingdom, the Commonwealth, the Economic Community of West African States (ECOWAS) and other nations with a
>   reciprocal via abolition agreement with the Gambia do not require a
>   visa to enter the country; whether on holiday or on a business trip
>   not exceeding 90 days.

Comment: While I think the conclusion here is probably right, note that Wikipedia's "Visa policy of Somewhereistan" articles usually do not attempt to describe the situation for people traveling on refugee documents. Sometimes they do -- e.g. [Visa policy of Ireland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Ireland) -- but most don't; e.g. [Visa policy of the Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area) does not even mention the complex situation where _some_ of the Schengen states allow visa-free travel with some, but not all, countries' refugee travel documents.